# How is mean square error (MSE) calculated in this case?

Tags: self-study, mse

Can Mean Square Error (MSE) be applied to decide which model is better?-i have two tables that present the residuals of two different models with the same number of parameters(29).

Comment: Twenty-nine parameters is too many.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: Really? Regardless of the number of observations, the magnitude of the error variance relative to that of the coefficients, the type of model-fitting procedure used; it's just too many?

Answer (score 1):

In general the lowest MSE the better the model.

So, for each model you have the difference between the real value and the model estimates (fitted values). The difference between those two is the residual for each observation (y - y_fitted = residual).

You can use this to calculate the MSE for each model and see which model is better.

Comment: This answer is wrong when so many parameters are used. Also your explanation of how MSE is calculated is not correct.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Given that this post has the tag "self-study", I didn't say how the MSE is calculated and I didn't give away the complete formula, I just said that he can use the residuals (y_fitted - y_real) to calculate the MSE. That being said, I know what you mean about the parameters but putting that aside, in general lower MSE indicates better model fit. Obviously I don't want to go into too much detail about the problems of overfitting